# Get the id of <li> tag containing a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list as:

```
 <ul>
 <li id="l1">1</li>
 <li id="l2">2</li>
 <li id="l3">hi</li>
 </ul>
```

By using jquery, i got to know if any `<li>` contains value(say) hi.
For that i used:

```
if($('li:contains('hi')')){
    alert('Got value');
}
```

Now i want to know the id of the `<li>` in which i found value 'hi'.
How do i get that id?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this:

```
var id = $('li:contains("hi")').attr('id');
```

<kbd>[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/arulmr/XU53p/)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

```
var id = $('li:contains("hi")').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the ID is simple attribute, you could do:

```
.attr("id")
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var id = jQuery('li:contains("hi")').attr('id');
```